# Visual Studio Microsoft.NETFramework.props was not found

Tags: visual-studio, .net-framework-version

After writing a program in C# (using Visual Studio Community 2013) I uninstalled Visual Studio from my computer. Then I installed it Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop. When I tried to open the earlier created project the following error appeared:

> the imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.NETFramework.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets

The same is happening when I am creating a new project. I have Framework 4.5.1 installed. On the help site I only found the hint to reinstall the program.